# Jquery Datatable - need to center the data first then right align

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I am using data-table in my application which contains text and #'s as data and use the following data alignments:

1) Text data - left aligned
2) Header data - center aligned
3) #'s - center the data first then right align

I have achieved the first two alignments by using data-table's default classes '**dt-left**' and '**dt-center**'. But I am unable achieve the 3rd alignment either by using '**dt-center**' and '**dt-right**' classes.

Please find the attached screen-cap for the expected and actual alignments.

**Expected #'s alignment**:

[image: Expected alignment]

**Actual #'s alignment**:

[image: Actual alignment]

I had achieved the expected behavior by simply providing '**padding**' for . But I want to know is there any other efficient/default option available in data-table to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want numbers to right aligned?

Comment: You have to place  '<div>' with a fix width (for exmple 80%) in your '<td>' then set the class 'dt-center' on the td and 'dt-right' on the div. Btw it would be useful to have some code

Comment: Yes, show your code, otherwise it is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows the `columns.className` option being used to center align the text in the final column of a `datatable`:

```
 $('#myTable').DataTable( {
      columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: -1,
            className: 'dt-body-center'
        }
      ]
    } );
```

Please refer : https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes for more information.